# Chain Puzzle: Video Games #02 - Fish Is You

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, grid-deduction, mazes, video-games

<sub>This is the second [Chain Puzzle](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7018/chain-puzzle-within-scope-for-pse) in the [Video Games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%22chain+puzzle%22+title%3A%22video+games%22+is%3Aquestion) series, in which all puzzles are themed around video games of all genres. The answer to this puzzle is a thematic word or phrase. The solver whose answer is awarded the green checkmark has the first refusal on the opportunity to create the next puzzle in the series, which must somehow incorporate the answer to this puzzle somewhere within its construction. The solver is under no obligation to create the next puzzle - in the event that the solver does not wish to take up this opportunity, the puzzle's setter may take up the offer of a willing substitute setter or choose to continue the chain themselves.</sub>

<sub>The answer to the [previous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106694/chain-puzzle-video-games-01-teleporting-crosswords) (which provided the theme for this one) was **BABA IS YOU**.</sub>

---

This puzzle mimics the mechanism of [Baba Is You](https://www.hempuli.com/baba/) by Arvi Teikari. Rules spelt out on the playing field horizontally or vertically, without spaces, are followed by every object in the playing field. The player moves whatever object is "you", making horizontal and vertical moves. For example, at the start "fish is you"; this means that the player moves the fish around the grid. If at some point you make "(something else) is you" out of the words in the playing field, then you move that piece from there on.

The goal is to move the object under control into the same square as the object designated "win". For example, if it says "fish is win" somewhere on the playing field, you win by moving into the square with the fish in it. A square containing an object designated "stop" cannot be moved into, and an object designated "push" can be pushed forwards by the object under control by standing next to it and moving towards it. Rule words are always pushed and can be used to form new rules.

How do you win this game? What are we playing next?

[image: "Fish Is You" puzzle grid]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To win this game, you follow this path:

> [image: image, annotated with lines showing the path]
>
>  First, make PINE IS YOU. The rest of the movement will be done with the tree.
>
>  With the tree, first you must enter the inside room, then go into the back room to extract BULB. Then, make BULB IS WIN and leave; finally, solve the classic "three crates in a row" Sokoban setup at the bottom, and go left to the bulb!

To solve the puzzle,

> There are several orders these actions could be performed in, and there are some unnecessary visits you could make as well. But this solution, and any other reasonably efficient solution, will spell out the same thing with the red letters: **TETRIS**.

Comment: When you pass "T" and push "BULB" right by one square, how is it possible to move right again? Isn't "BULB" already as far right as it will go?

Comment: @COTO You go through the other way! BULB is pushed to the *left*, not the right.

Comment: "Fish is you" remains in place for this entire (and any) solution which means that while you are controlling another thing the fish will be flailing about randomly. There's nothing the fish can mess up at that point but it's funny to me.

Answer (score 11):

Deusovi's answer is surely correct, but this puzzle has multiple solutions - at least if all the normal Baba is You rules are in play.

Here is a qualitatively different solution, which ends in a different position. Follow the lines in ROYGBV order.

> [image]

Explanation:

> **Red**: Start by making `Peak is You`. Either answer works here, but we'll use Peak to be different from the existing answer. Future moves will be done as Peak.
>  **Orange**: Retrieve `Moon` and place it two spaces below `Sea`.
>  **Yellow**: Grab `Is` and place it between `Sea` and `Moon` to form `Sea is Moon`. `Bomb` will get bumped during the shuffle, but that doesn't matter.
>  **Green**: Replace `Is` back to its original position.
>  **Blue**: Push `Moon` over to form `Moon is Win`.
>  **Violet**: Move to the location where Sea was, but since `Sea Is Moon` was true for a moment, that space now has a Moon, so you win.

This forms the message:

> CTEARN. Which is nonsense, but maybe anagrams to "TEN CAR"? Either way, this surely isn't the intended answer - but in typical Baba is You fashion, knowledge of the full ruleset opens complex solutions to early puzzles.

Comment: Ah, that's clever! It didn't occur to me to check symbol-is-symbol logic. Probably should have played the game a bit further before making this!

Comment: @Jafe - I think this is a case of a convincing-enough red herring accidentally being part of a solution. My thought was that the `IS` would be flush with the south wall if it wasn't "meant" to be used in other rules, so I looked for ways to use it. Even then, though, I knew this answer was dubious because you didn't mention anything about the transformation rules in your question.